# Can't from PIL import Image?

Tags: python

I have tried to install pillow version 7.0.0 but get the following error below. Please suggest a solution.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-b7f01c2f8cfe> in <module>
----> 1 from PIL import Image

~\Anaconda3\envs\streamlined\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in <module>
     42 # PILLOW_VERSION was removed in Pillow 7.0.0.
     43 # Use __version__ instead.
---> 44 from . import ImageMode, TiffTags, UnidentifiedImageError, __version__, _plugins
     45 from ._binary import i8, i32le
     46 from ._util import deferred_error, isPath

ImportError: cannot import name 'UnidentifiedImageError' from 'PIL' (unknown location)
```

Comment: This question shouldn't be downvoted so many times. I had the same issue and after hours of trials and errors, I solved it by rebooting... https://github.com/home-assistant/core/issues/32953#issuecomment-600874611

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a library that you are using, or that is interfacing with PIL/Pillow was built for a previous version, so you either need to update the library/code calling PIL/Pillow, or install the version of Pillow that your library/code is written for.

Example of how to install pillow version 5.0.0

```
$ pip install pillow==5.0.0
```